# Is it legal to use “VMware Workstation 15 Player” with earning money purpose?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, internet, software, licensing

I am planning to open a blog webpage, publish technology-based content on it and make money via blogger earning methods like Google AdSense. The software I mentioned in the title, which is available at [here](https://www.vmware.com/tr/products/workstation-player/workstation-player-evaluation.html), is just one of the necessities to prepare my content.

However, firstly, I want to be sure whether this kind of usage is legal or not for this software. When I look at the link I added, there is an expression in the form of "The free version is available for non-commercial, personal and home use."

According to this statement, is it legal for me to use this software as I have stated?

Comment: @RonBeyer please don’t answer the in comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Not the free version

Your use is commercial so you have to buy the software which (presumably) allows commercial use.

Comment: Or, obviously, use something similar which isn't under a non-commercial licence. However, this isn't the place to discuss alternatives.